# Equivalent form of biconditional

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm reading *How to Prove It: A Structured Approach* (Velleman) Second Ed.

Doing all the end of chapter exercises for chapter 1 and having trouble on problem 5a which reads

> Show that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $(P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$

Clearly they're equivalent to each other based on the truth tables. But is that really the best way to 'show' it? I was able to derive the second form from the first in all the other questions that asked to show two forms are equivalent so far.

Here's what happens when I try to derive it:

> $$P \leftrightarrow Q$$
>   $$ \text{Form of biconditional} $$
>   $$(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow P)$$
>   $$ \text{Form of conditional}$$
>   $$ (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P)$$

From here it appears to match the form of a distributive law but with mismatched negations. I just don't know where to go from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, so good.  To continue...

$\vdots \\
(\neg P \vee Q)\wedge (\neg Q\vee P)
\\ \Updownarrow (\text{Distribute})\\
(\neg P\wedge (\neg Q\vee P)) \vee (Q\wedge (\neg Q\vee P))
\\ \Updownarrow (\text{Distribute, twice})\\
(\neg P\wedge \neg Q)\vee(\neg P\wedge P)\vee (Q\wedge \neg Q)\vee (Q\wedge P)
\\ \Updownarrow  \\
\vdots
$

Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: You'd remove the two contradictions because of the contradiction laws and be left with (not P && not Q) || (Q && P), then use commutative laws to arrive at exactly the answer?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Are you comfortable with the distributions?

Comment: Yes I worked out your answer. I was going to edit the question mark and say thanks when my internet went out, so thanks for that.